# Canvas hit area offset after window is resized (using Paper.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, responsive

I'm trying to make a simple paper.js demo responsive, so that it has a fixed canvas width and height attribute and scales down when the window is resized.
Here is the live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/quanchi/mg7k4x8r/24/

Works fine (can move the blobs) until window is resized and everything scaled down. Then there seems to be an offset which seems to be impossible to fix. Please advise.

```
      canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:100% !important;
        height:100% !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>
```

PS: Here is the original demo, that is not responsive (does not scale down when window is resized):
http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/

I expected the canvas to work properly after applying fixed canvas width and height but there seems to be an offset in mouse coordinates after resizing the window. When refreshing the page in any window size it works fine but after resizing there is an offset.